# Google Cloud Function not recognizing Papaparse 5.0 Dependency

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, papaparse

I am building a Node.js Google Cloud function, and it is not recognizing the dependency "papaparse":
in package.json

```
      "dependencies": {
    "papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "twilio": "^3.33.2"
  }
```

Error code I am getting:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'papaparse'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

I have tried reinstalling papaparse, running npm audit, but those steps haven't helped. 
Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Ddid you `npm i --save papaparse` ?

Comment: You can't act on a Cloud Functions instance mem, so you can't npm i --save papaparse. You must import from package.json

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to deploy a Cloud Function with papaparse.

For this you just need to deploy your function from the Cloud Shell. First create a folder where you gonna insert all your files. Then clone the repo from the [papaparse github](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) with the command `git clone` into that folder.

Now after adding your Index.json and your Package.json you can deploy your Cloud Function following this [Deploying from Your Local Machine](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem) documentation.